# Changing font size or using scalebox for music with abc package

Tags: fontsize, music

I am trying to typeset some music using the abc package (see below). Is there any way to increase the font size of the text of the song, or (even better) to scale the whole music to be bigger? I tried to use scalebox, but got the error "Argument of \verbatim@ has an extra }. " Thank you for your help!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[generate,ps2eps]{abc}
\usepackage[left=2.3cm,right=2.3cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2cm,footskip=0cm {geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[light,math]{iwona}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\scalebox{2}{
\begin{abc}[name=saints]
X: 1 % start of header
K: A % scale: C major
M:4/4 %Meter 
A2  c2      d2 |    (e8 | e2)   A2 c2   d2 |    (e8 | e2)   
w:  Oh, when    the     saints _    go mar- ching    in   _  \ 
A2 c2   d2 |    e4      c4 |  A4   c4 |   (B8 | B2)
w:  oh when the     saints  go    mar- ching  in _ \
c2  c2   B2 | A6 A2 | c4   e4 | e2   (d6 | d2) 
w:  I   want to   be a-   mong the  num- ber _  \
d2 c2   d2 | e4      c4 |    A4      B4 | (A8 | A2) |]
w:  oh when the  Saints  go      march-  ing  in _ \
\end{abc}
}

Some text.
```

Thank you for your help!

Edit: I use windows, so to run the whole thing I write the following in the command prompt: 
`latex --shell-escape abc3
abcm2ps -E  saints saints`

Then I rename saints001.eps in saints.eps
Then I run

`latex --shell-escape abc3
dvips -o abc3.ps abc3.dvi
ps2pdf abc3.ps
pdflatex --shell-escape --interaction=errorstopmode --synctex=-1 abc3`

Comment: please fix the example, as it it just produces `! Argument of \@fileswith@ptions has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.5 \usepackage
               {graphicx}
? `

Comment: Hi David, without the scalebox the example runs for me. I can't reproduce the error you get. :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to pass the suitable options to `abcm2ps`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[generate,ps2eps]{abc}
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[light,math]{iwona}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\begin{abc}[name=saints]
X: 1 % start of header
K: A % scale: C major
M:4/4 %Meter 
A2  c2      d2 |    (e8 | e2)   A2 c2   d2 |    (e8 | e2)   
w:  Oh, when    the     saints _    go mar- ching    in   _  \ 
A2 c2   d2 |    e4      c4 |  A4   c4 |   (B8 | B2)
w:  oh when the     saints  go    mar- ching  in _ \
c2  c2   B2 | A6 A2 | c4   e4 | e2   (d6 | d2) 
w:  I   want to   be a-   mong the  num- ber _  \
d2 c2   d2 | e4      c4 |    A4      B4 | (A8 | A2) |]
w:  oh when the  Saints  go      march-  ing  in _ \
\end{abc}

Some text.

\begin{abc}[name=saints2,options={-O= -c -s 1.2}]
X: 1 % start of header
K: A % scale: C major
M:4/4 %Meter 
A2  c2      d2 |    (e8 | e2)   A2 c2   d2 |    (e8 | e2)   
w:  Oh, when    the     saints _    go mar- ching    in   _  \ 
A2 c2   d2 |    e4      c4 |  A4   c4 |   (B8 | B2)
w:  oh when the     saints  go    mar- ching  in _ \
c2  c2   B2 | A6 A2 | c4   e4 | e2   (d6 | d2) 
w:  I   want to   be a-   mong the  num- ber _  \
d2 c2   d2 | e4      c4 |    A4      B4 | (A8 | A2) |]
w:  oh when the  Saints  go      march-  ing  in _ \
\end{abc}

Some text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi egreg, thanks for your help. When I run your example, the music is both times the same  (small) size. I think this is because I run "abcm2ps -E -O saints2 saints2" via the command prompt (I'll add above to my original questions how I run abc).  I tried changeing it to "abcm2ps -E options={-O= -c -s 1.2}  saints2 saints2", but that results in "error: Invalid parameter <1.2}> for flag -s". Could you tell me how I use these options correctly in the command prompt? And what exactly does -c and -s mean? Sorry for all the questions, I can't find a manual for abc or abcm2ps... Thanks!!

Comment: @Dominika I know almost nothing about `abcm2ps`; the default command line options for it are `-O= -c`, so I just added `-s 1.2` to ask for magnification. I ran exactly the example and the output is as shown.

Comment: Thanks, @egreg . I figured it out now, with the help of this list of abcm2ps options: http://trillian.mit.edu/~jc/music/abc/src/abcm2ps-6.6.1/options.txt . Running `abcm2ps -E -s 1.2 -O saints saints` from the command prompt works in my case.